# Methods to prove $\frac{21n + 4}{14n + 3}$ is irreducible for every natural number $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, fractions

Prove $\frac{21n + 4}{14n + 3}$ is irreducible for every natural number $n$.

I was thinking of taking a number-theory based approach.

Can you suggest the following method

**Calculus/Number theory based methods?** Please take a look at my attempt here.

Assume $\frac{21n + 4}{14n + 3}$ **is** reducible so we can apply modular arithmethic, considering the numerator and denominator seperately.  Ideas here,

$21n + 4 \equiv 4 (\mod 7)$
$14n + 3 \equiv 3 (\mod 7)$

$35n + 7 \equiv 7 (\mod 7)$

Taking the LHS separately, $35n + 7 (\mod 7) \equiv DNE$ there is no residue since there is no remainder.

Therefore, by contradiction, it is true?

Thanks!

Comment: You have shown that the numerator and denominator differ $\pmod 7$, but they could conceivably both be multiples of $11$, say.  $\LaTeX$ hints:  Instead of $==$ we usually use \equiv to get $\equiv$ when saying things are congruent and \pmod 7 gives $\pmod 7$ so you get the mod in the correct font.

Comment: Note that this is [IMO 1959/1](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/resources.php?c=1&cid=16&year=1959&sid=3853966da41a091369b43e1a09846162).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to show that $21n+4$ and $14n+3$ are relatively prime. Note that
$$(3)(14n+3)-(2)(21n+4)=1.$$
So any common divisor of $21n+4$ and $14n+3$ divides $1$.

**Remark:** I am not able to construct an argument based on the post. The remainder when $(21n+4)+(14n+3)$ is divided by $7$ is $0$, I would not use DNE, since $0$ is a perfectly respectable remainder. But working modulo $7$ is not enough, we want to rule out *all* common divisors greater than $1$.

Answer (score 3):

gcd(21n+4, 14n+3) = gcd(14n+3, 7n+1) = gcd(7n+2, 7n+1) = gcd(7n+1, 1) = 1

Using repeated usage of Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

A simple one-line proof:
$$\gcd(21n+4,14n+3)=\gcd(7n+1,14n+3)=\gcd(7n+1,7n+2)=1.$$

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of taninamdar's answer (posted 1 hour prior).