# Prove that $\frac{21n+4}{14n+3}$ is in lowest terms for any natural $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Prove that the fraction $\dfrac{21n+4}{14n+3}$ is in lowest terms for any natural value of $n$.

Comment: Complex numbers are not numbers that are complicated! :-o

Comment: Any thoughts yourself? Why can't the numerator and denominator both be divided by $2$, $3$, $5$, $7$ or any other primes?

Comment: Anyway, use the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to find GCD of $21n+4$ and $14n+3$.  What should the GCD be, if the fraction is always irreducible?

Comment: @BrianTung  You just made me choke.

Comment: @Batominovski: I do apologize!  It appears your keyboard is unimpaired, though, thankfully.

Comment: $$2(21n+4)-3(14n+3)=?$$

Comment: For reference, this is IMO 1959, Problem 1---**the first ever IMO problem**.  See https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=1959_IMO_Problems/Problem_1.

Comment: If $d$ is a common divisor of both numerator and denominator, then $d$ divides any linear combination of the two. In particular, $d$ divides $2(21n+4)-3(14n+3)=-1$.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: Duplicate of [Prove the following fraction is irreducible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943231/prove-the-following-fraction-is-irreducible)

Comment: Dupe of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383366/idea-behind-proof-that-frac21n414n3-is-irreducible-for-all-n)

Answer (score 7):

Writing $(n,m)$ for the GCD of $m$ and $n$, immediately one has $(n,m)=(n,m-kn)$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then
$$
(21n+4,14n+3)=(7n+1,14n+3)=(7n+1,1)=1.
$$

Thus $21n+4$ and $14n+3$ are coprime, so their ratio is in lowest terms.

Answer (score 2):

For starters such as yourself, you can begin by assuming otherwise. That is the fraction is reducible. So $\exists k  \in \mathbb{N}, k > 1$ such that $k \mid 21n + 4, k \mid 14n+3\implies 21n+4 = ak, 14n+3 = bk$ for some natural numbers $a,b$. Thus: $42n+8 = 2ak, 42n+9 = 3bk\implies 3bk - 2ak = 1\implies k(3b-2a) = 1\implies k = 1$, contradicting the assumption that $k > 1$. This means $\text{gcd}(21n+4,14n+3) = 1$ or $\dfrac{21n+4}{14n+3}$ is irreducible.